# Issue splitting mesh in half to model, then duplicating/merging back together

Tags: mesh, vertices

I usually model stuff by splitting it in half, doing my modeling, then when I'm done duplicating, flipping and joining them together. But for whatever reason, when I join the vertices, they spike up?

[image]
https://youtu.be/MaQM_OVARiE

Comment: mbs answer  is prob on track re normals and how to fix, however Consider elaborating more on the method used re how you are getting to result  _"flipping them and joining them together"_  (assume its dupe scale by -1 in x and join?)  IMO use the mirror modifier. Apply it when done, and normals are taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

It must be because you have flipped normals, so simply recalculate the normals.